# Notification that iCloud import began

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, icloud

Is there any notification to check that import of `iCloud` changes began to the persistent store?

I want to show progress for the user for that process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CoreData there's one of the longest NSNotification ever:

```
NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
```

But it is only fired at the end of the process, then you have to refresh the store, and inform the user in the meantime.

Otherwise I didn't find any pre icloud notification of the process going to happen.

There is also another notification, but again this has nothing to do about iCloud starting, and that is:

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification
```

Comment: @Shmidt So there is not a way to inform user about the start of the sync process.